# Laravel Search ошибка установки

Tags: laravel

Установил Laravel Scout согласно следующей инструкции:

1) Выполнил команду `composer require laravel/scout`

2) Добавил расширение в providers `'Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider::class,'`

3) Выполнил команду `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"`

4) Добавил расширение в Model

```
Laravel\Scout\Searchable
use Searchable;
```

5) Выполнил команду `composer require algolia/algoliasearch-client-php`

6) Модель выглядит сейчас вот так:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use DB;

class Product extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
    protected $table = 'products';

    public static function getProductsBySearch($search)
    {
        // Список найденных продуктов
        $searchProducts = Product::search('Test')
            ->get()
            ->all();
        return $searchProducts;
    }

}
```

На выходе получаю ошибку:

```
AlgoliaSearch requires an applicationID
```

Как решить данную проблему? Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Algolia - это поисковый сервис, куда вы должны будете отправлять документы на индексацию, а за тем оттуда получать выборки по запросу.

1. Вы должны зарегистрироваться на https://www.algolia.com/
2. В личном кабинете получить app_id и scecret_key
3. Указать их конфиге Laravel (.env)

ALGOLIA_APP_ID=XXXXX

ALGOLIA_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXX

4. Отправить данные на индексацию:

   php artisan scout:import "App\Product"

В личном кабинете Algolia можно убедиться что данные получены.